# Prevent pattern from scaling when object scales

Tags: fabricjs

I can't figure out a way to apply a pattern repeat fill to an object or shape and have it not scale when the object is scaled.

Even if I recreate the object and apply the pattern again it gets distorted if the object is scaled at all or on an ellipse that is wider than it is tall or vice versa.

Surely there is a way to apply a repeat pattern fill to a shape and have it applied after any transformations?

Any ideas or example appreciated, project is being held up by this one key issue

Thanks

Comment: I don't have entire solution for you but you need to look at size and scale properties of your object, because built-in scaling in fabricjs changes object scale, not its size. If you find any way to keep your scale constant but change object size during resize you'll get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you "apply" the scale after the objected is resized then the pattern will not scale. eg

```
rect1.on('modified', function() {
  rect1.set({width:rect1.width*rect1.scaleX,scaleX:1,height:rect1.height*rect1.scaleY, scaleY:1}); // apply the scale
  rect1.setCoords(); // called so that the bounding box etc gets updated
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is a really old question, but I had the same type of issue today. And for people who'll find their way to this question, here's how to do it while scaling:

```
fabricObject.on('scaling', function() {
  this.set({
    width : this.width  * this.scaleX,
    height: this.height * this.scaleY,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
  });
});
```

This will not scale your object on the canvas while pulling the handles, simply update the width and height of your component.

Doing as [@rabidgremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785569/673125) suggested will only do this after you've finished your scaling, not during.